# NestJs, applyDecorators does not work for @ApiOperation decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, decorator

I want to combine multiple decorator in NestJs using the function `applyDecorators` however the `ApiOperation {...}` decorator it seems to be override by a default empty one generated by default.

My combined decorator looks like this

```
export function OApiDocumentationBasicRead(entity: string): <TFunction extends () => void, Y>(
  target: object | TFunction,
  propertyKey?: string | symbol,
  descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Y>,
) => void {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiOperation({
      summary: `Retrieves a single entity given its ID`,
    }),
    ...
  );
}
```

The transpiled code looks like this:

```
__decorate([
    openapi.ApiOperation({ description: "" }), // GENERATED BY DEFAULT AND CAUSING ISSUE
    (0, oapi_crud_decorator_1.OApiDocumentationBasicRead)('user'),
    openapi.ApiResponse({ status: 200, type: require("./entities/user.entity").User }),
    ...
]...);

function OApiDocumentationBasicRead(entity) {
    return (0, common_1.applyDecorators)((0, swagger_1.ApiOperation)({
      summary: `Retrieves a single ${entity} given its ID`,
    })
  );
}
```

How do I get rid of the default empty

```
openapi.ApiOperation({ description: "" }),
```